# mysql - How to limit certain records in a SELECT query

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Okay, so I have a relation of students who enrolled in multiple subjects. Most of the students were enrolled in only one year, either 2015 or 2016, but I have one that is enrolled in subjects from 2015 but also had some in 2016. I want to be able to show the students who were enrolled in 2015 only. However, when I do my SELECT statement, I am also grabbing the one student who did the subject in 2016 as well. The subject code includes the year the subject was done in.

Some of the data from the enrolled relation:

[image]

Code:

```
SELECT s.firstName, d.degreeCode
FROM students s, degrees d, enrolled e
WHERE s.studentID = d.studentID AND s.studentID = e.studentID AND e.subjectCode NOT LIKE '_______16__'
GROUP BY firstName;
```

So I am obtaining all of the students who studied in 15, but I don't want s3 in the result table as he also studied in 2016.

Comment: Storing the year, in which a course took place, in the `SubjectCode` seems like a bad idea. Why not make a separate column for that in the `enrolled` table?

Comment: This kind of problem can be symptomatic of poor design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach uses aggregation to assert that a given student's subject code only occurs in a single year.

```
SELECT s.firstName, d.degreeCode
FROM students s
INNER JOIN degrees d
    ON s.studentID = d.studentID
INNER JOIN ENTROLLED e
    s.studentID = e.studentID
WHERE
    SUBSTRING(e.subjectCode, 8, 2)) = '15' AND
    s.studentID NOT IN (
        SELECT d.studentID
        FROM degrees d
        INNER JOIN enrolled e
            ON d.studentID = e.studentID
        GROUP BY d.studentID
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT SUBSTRING(e.subjectCode, 8, 2)) > 1
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check for the all the student  NOT IN the  select for student  LIKE  '_______16__'

```
SELECT s.firstName, d.degreeCode
FROM students s  
INNER JOIN degrees d ON s.studentID = d.studentID
INNER JOIN enrolled e  AND s.studentID = e.studentID 
WHERE s.StudentID NOT IN (
    select studentID 
    FROM students s
    INNER JOIN degrees d ON s.studentID = d.studentID
    INNER JOIN enrolled e  AND s.studentID = e.studentID 
    WHERE e.subjectCode NOT LIKE  '%_15_%'

)
```

Comment: This could be more flexible if you say: `WHERE e.subjectCode NOT LIKE  '%_15_%'`. So you exclude all students that did a course in another year than 2015, irrespective of what that year is.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware  correct  .. answer  updated  with your suggestion .. thanks